# Jasmine - TypeError: Cannot read property 'spyOn' of null

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am writing a unit test for a service with mocha/jasmine. My originial service is dependent on `NodeSrv` service. However, when I inject it in my unit test it doesn't look like it's really injecting the dependency `NodeSrv` service. I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'spyOn' of null`

```
describe("Label Exists Check Service", function() {
  var LabelExistsCheck;
  var NodeSvc;
  var VipSvc;

  beforeEach(function() {
    return module("main");
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function(_LabelExistsCheck_, _NodeSvc_, _VipSvc_) {
    LabelExistsCheck = _LabelExistsCheck_;
    NodeSvc = _NodeSvc_;
    VipSvc = _VipSvc_;
  }));

  describe("It should check if node label exists", function() {
    spyOn(NodeSvc, "getNodes").and.returnValue(["testing1", "foo"]);
    newLabelName = "testing1";
    oldLabelName = "nada";


    devices = NodeSvc.getNodes();
    deviceExist =  devices.some(function(element) {
      if (newLabelName == element) {
        return true
      }});

    //spyOn(form, "$setValidity");

    it("node label should already exist and call set form", function() {
      expect(NodeSvc.getNodes).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

---

UPDATE:

Tried the below and got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'returnValue' of undefined`:

```
describe("Label Exists Check Service", function() {
  var LabelExistsCheck;
  var NodeSvc;
  var VipSvc;

  beforeEach(function() {
    return module("main");
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function(_LabelExistsCheck_, _NodeSvc_, _VipSvc_) {
    LabelExistsCheck = _LabelExistsCheck_;
    NodeSvc = _NodeSvc_;
    VipSvc = _VipSvc_;
  }));

  beforeEach(function() {
    spyOn(NodeSvc, "getNodes").and.returnValue(["testing1", "foo"]);
  });


  it("It should check if node label exists", function() {
    newLabelName = "testing1";
    oldLabelName = "nada";


    devices = NodeSvc.getNodes();
    deviceExist =  devices.some(function(element) {
      if (newLabelName == element) {
        return true
      }});

    //spyOn(form, "$setValidity");

  });
});
```

Comment: Remove `NodeSvc` from `function(NodeSvc) {` in `describe("It should check if node label exists",` It will create a local variable that overrides the one outside.

Comment: I placed `NodeSvc` for troubleshooting. I removed it but still get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'spyOn' of null`

Comment: What happens when you change `describe("It should check if node label exists", function() {` to `it("..."` ? http://plnkr.co/edit/C7CBE4?p=preview

Comment: Updated bottom of post with new modification... got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'returnValue' of undefined`

Comment: Which version of jasmine are you using? Check my plunker above.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/uBvwKvpNpjegjAlb93qU the error is now a little different. I am using `jasmine-fixture": "~1.2.0"`, `"jasmine-given": "~2.6.2"`, `"jasmine-given": "~2.6.2"`

Comment: You put wrong module.. `module("myApp")` instead of `module("main")`

Comment: ah...ok. works now in the plunker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the old syntax of `.andReturn` works instead. Not sure what is broken in my system, since I was/still am using Jasmine 2.0.

UPDATE: in testem config...I need to specify `jasmine2` even if jasmine < 2 is not installed.

Comment: what's "testem config..." ?

Comment: the config file for testem